# Returning JSON from a PHP Script

Tags: php, json, header

I want to return JSON from a PHP script.

Do I just echo the result? Do I have to set the `Content-Type` header?

Comment: Always set the Content-Type header for json, to avoid XSS. Observe the difference between these two scripts: <?php print json_encode(["someKey" => "<body onload=alert(1)>"]); ?> and <?php header("Content-Type: application/json");print json_encode(["someKey" => "<body onload=alert(1)>"]); ?> For more information see: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/169427/impact-of-the-response-content-type-on-the-exploitability-of-xss [Not able to submit an answer due to reputation requirement]

Answer (score 2047, accepted):

While you're usually fine without it, you can and should set the `Content-Type` header:

```
<?php
$data = /** whatever you're serializing **/;
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($data);
```

If I'm not using a particular framework, I usually allow some request params to modify the output behavior.  It can be useful, generally for quick troubleshooting, to not send a header, or sometimes `print_r` the data payload to eyeball it (though in most cases, it shouldn't be necessary).

Comment: just in case: you should use header() commands only in addition with output buffering to avoid "headers already sent" warnings

Comment: It's good practice to always put your header() statements as far to the top of the page as possible so that when you add more code, you aren't tempted to insert code before the header() statement which could break things if you start outputting.

Comment: @mikepote I actually don't think it's necessary to have the header command at the top of the PHP file. If you're inadvertently spitting out stuff and that's tripping up your header command, you just need to fix your code because it's broken.

Comment: @Halfstop sure, it's just recommended for ease of debugging, but I dont always do it either.

Comment: Adding a `header` to a PHP script is the correct way to do things, You do not want to pass a HTML type document to something expecting JSON/JS... Simple.... While something like jQuery will auto parse, not everything does... If you supply dynamic content via PHP, always post the headers if you can.. Debugging, i normally use a `isset($_REQUEST['debug'])` and do something like `echo "<pre>".print_r($oRET,true)."</pre>";`

Comment: Routinely, the last two lines of my action page that returns a json string is the header statement, followed by the `echo json_encode($data);`, exactly as @timdev shows it. The only thing I do differently (and it's inconsequential to the problem) is I put my `$data = array();` at the top of my php page. I actually want my Ajax return to break. If you use something like `.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) { alert( "Request failed: " + jqXHR + ", " + textStatus ); });` in your ajax block, it will tell you what went wrong, and even where. Eventually you will make your action page bullet proof.

Comment: @KrzysztofKalinowski no, the PHP file doesn't need to be UTF-8 encoded. the output MUST be UTF-8 encoded. Those wrong statements doesn't help non-experienced users to learn how to avoid things from breaking, but it helps to grow myths on them and never learning which role does encodings play on streams and how they work.

Comment: @timdev don't forget to call `exit();` of `die();` right after `echo json_encode($data);`, otherwise random data from your script (e.g profiling) might get appended to your json response.

Comment: @TimoHuovinen the default encoding is UTF8, always.

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub You are right, the charset is redundant and ignored.

Comment: "doesn't need to be UTF-8 encoded". This is **not true** if you have literal strings with special characters in your PHP file. Without your PHP file being encoded in UTF-8, the following code will return incorrect characters: `<?php $responseData = [{ "title":"¿Y Tú Qué Has Hecho"}];header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8'); echo $responseData;`

Comment: My last line of such script is usually `die(json_encode($data));`. I use more-or-less the same in mid-lines where an error is caught, so I sent the error response to JS, and because the script stops there, I don't need an `else` or similar.

Comment: Use die; after echo statement, otherwise as rightly said by @BinarWeb json data gets corrupted and won't be as expected. Do not use exit as it also does not work properly, use only die

Comment: @Aditya in my case, I don't use `die`, I only use `exit`. Never had an issue.

Comment: @BinarWeb not sure why, but for me exit is not working as expected, only die is working properly. Strange and no explanation :-)

Answer (score 155):

A complete piece of nice and clear PHP code returning JSON is:

```
$option = $_GET['option'];

if ( $option == 1 ) {
    $data = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];
    // will encode to JSON array: ["a","b","c"]
    // accessed as example in JavaScript like: result[1] (returns "b")
} else {
    $data = [ 'name' => 'God', 'age' => -1 ];
    // will encode to JSON object: {"name":"God","age":-1}  
    // accessed as example in JavaScript like: result.name or result['name'] (returns "God")
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode( $data );
```

Comment: You should probably be doing: `$option = isset($_GET['option']);` beforehand.

Comment: ```$option = isset($_GET['option']) ? trim($_GET['option']) : null;```

Answer (score 66):

According to the [manual on `json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#refsect1-function.json-encode-returnvalues) the method can return a non-string (**false**):

> Returns a JSON encoded string on success or `FALSE` on failure.

When this happens `echo json_encode($data)` will output the empty string, which is [invalid JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621802/why-does-json-parse-fail-with-the-empty-string).

`json_encode` will for instance fail (and return `false`) if its argument contains a non UTF-8 string.

This error condition should be captured in PHP, for example like this:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");

// Collect what you need in the $data variable.

$json = json_encode($data);
if ($json === false) {
    // Avoid echo of empty string (which is invalid JSON), and
    // JSONify the error message instead:
    $json = json_encode(["jsonError" => json_last_error_msg()]);
    if ($json === false) {
        // This should not happen, but we go all the way now:
        $json = '{"jsonError":"unknown"}';
    }
    // Set HTTP response status code to: 500 - Internal Server Error
    http_response_code(500);
}
echo $json;
?>
```

Then the receiving end should of course be aware that the presence of the *jsonError* property indicates an error condition, which it should treat accordingly.

In production mode it might be better to send only a generic error status to the client and log the more specific error messages for later investigation.

Read more about dealing with JSON errors in [PHP's Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php).

Comment: There's no `charset` parameter for JSON; see the note at the end of https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8259#section-11: "No 'charset' parameter is defined for this registration. Adding one really has no effect on compliant recipients." (JSON must be transmitted as UTF-8 per https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8259#section-8.1, so specifying that it's encoded as UTF-8 is a bit redundant.)

Comment: Thanks for highlighting that, @PatrickDark. Redundant `charset` parameter removed from HTTP header string.

Answer (score 41):

Try [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to encode the data and set the content-type with `header('Content-type: application/json');`.

Answer (score 37):

This question got many answers but none cover the entire process to return clean JSON with everything required to prevent the JSON response to be malformed.

```php
/*
 * returnJsonHttpResponse
 * @param $success: Boolean
 * @param $data: Object or Array
 */
function returnJsonHttpResponse($httpCode, $data)
{
    // remove any string that could create an invalid JSON 
    // such as PHP Notice, Warning, logs...
    ob_start();
    ob_clean();

    // this will clean up any previously added headers, to start clean
    header_remove(); 

    // Set the content type to JSON and charset 
    // (charset can be set to something else)
    // add any other header you may need, gzip, auth...
    header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");

    // Set your HTTP response code, refer to HTTP documentation
    http_response_code($httpCode);
    
    
    // encode your PHP Object or Array into a JSON string.
    // stdClass or array
    echo json_encode($data);

    // making sure nothing is added
    exit();
}
```

References:

[response_remove](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header-remove.php)

[ob_clean](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php)

[Content-type JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Metadata_and_schema)

[HTTP Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success)

[http_response_code](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php)

[json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: thnx for the ob_clean reference. I had a leading line that was jacking up my fetch response.json() calls.

Comment: What's the point of ob_clean if ob_start wasn't called?

Comment: what's the use of exit() when there are other shutdown handlers? and as @GinoPane commented, and then stacked output buffers? And imagine you remove headers and then it ruins the output compression. The road to hell is paved with good intentions. And if this fails, it's not deliberately an internal server error... .

Answer (score 28):

Set the content type with `header('Content-type: application/json');` and then echo your data.

Answer (score 22):

It is also good to set the access security - just replace * with the domain you want to be able to reach it.

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-type: application/json');
    $response = array();
    $response[0] = array(
        'id' => '1',
        'value1'=> 'value1',
        'value2'=> 'value2'
    );

echo json_encode($response); 
?>
```

Here is more samples on that: [how to bypass Access-Control-Allow-Origin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564832/how-to-bypass-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: What does it mean if this doesn't work?  For example, to restrict only to calls from CodePen, I tried `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://cdpn.io');`, but I can still load the page from my own browser.

Comment: it is used for blocking cross scripting (one script calling another page). So you will be able to load it directly from your browser, but you cant load it from another domain using script.

Answer (score 12):

A simple function to return a **JSON response** with the **HTTP status code**.

```
function json_response($data=null, $httpStatus=200)
{
    header_remove();

    header("Content-Type: application/json");

    http_response_code($httpStatus);

    echo json_encode($data);

    exit();
}
```

Comment: `header_remove`, and explicitly setting the http response is a good idea; although setting status and then http_response seems redundant.  Might also want to add an `exit` statement to the end.  I combined your function with @trincot 's: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35391449/339440

Comment: Using JS FetchAPI, could you extend your answer on how to receive sent data? `fetch(...).then(res => res.json()).then(data => /* do smth */).catch(e => console.error(e))` works great when response is `200`, but how to get `$data` on `500` to show the exact error thrown in PHP in the `.catch()` method in JS?

Comment: To achieve that you have to wrap your code in a try catch: `try {
    /* code... */
    json_response('Success!', 200);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    json_response($e->getMessage(), 500);
}`

Answer (score 10):

```
<?php
$data = /** whatever you're serializing **/;
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: What is the difference stating the charset in header? Please explain, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

As said above:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

will make the job. but keep in mind that :

- Ajax will have no problem to read json even if this header is not used, except if your json contains some HTML tags. In this case you need to set the header as application/json.
- Make sure your file is not encoded in UTF8-BOM. This format add a character in the top of the file, so your header() call will fail.

Answer (score 6):

**If you want js object use header content-type:**

```
<?php
$data = /** whatever you're serializing **/;
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($data);
```

**If you want only json : remove header content-type attribute, just encode and echo.**

```
<?php
$data = /** whatever you're serializing **/;
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-typeapplication/json.),

It says.

> The MIME media type for JSON text is
>   application/json.

so if you set the header to that type, and output your JSON string, it should work.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to get json from php sending custom information you can add this `header('Content-Type: application/json');` before to print any other thing, So then you can print you custome `echo '{"monto": "'.$monto[0]->valor.'","moneda":"'.$moneda[0]->nombre.'","simbolo":"'.$moneda[0]->simbolo.'"}';`

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you'll need to use echo to display output. Mimetype: application/json

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple PHP script to return male female and user id as json value will be any random value as you call the script json.php .

Hope this  help thanks

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/json");
$myObj=new \stdClass();
$myObj->user_id = rand(0, 10);
$myObj->male = rand(0, 5);
$myObj->female = rand(0, 5);
$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);
echo $myJSON;
?>
```

Comment: The MIME media type for JSON text is application/json

Answer (score 1):

If you query a database and need the result set in JSON format it can be done like this:

```
<?php

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mylogs");
//MSG
$query = "SELECT * FROM logs LIMIT 20";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
//Add all records to an array
$rows = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
    $rows[] = $row;
}
//Return result to jTable
$qryResult = array();
$qryResult['logs'] = $rows;
echo json_encode($qryResult);

mysqli_close($db);

?>
```

For help in parsing the result using jQuery take a look at [this tutorial](https://kodesmart.com/kode/working-with-json-jquery-php-and-mysql).

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are trying to return JSON response for API or else make sure you have proper headers and also make sure you return a valid JSON data.

***Here is the sample script which helps you to return JSON response from PHP array or 
from JSON file.***

> #### PHP Script (Code):

```php
<?php

// Set required headers
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

/**
 * Example: First
 *
 * Get JSON data from JSON file and retun as JSON response
 */

// Get JSON data from JSON file
$json = file_get_contents('response.json');

// Output, response
echo $json;

/** =. =.=. =.=. =.=. =.=. =.=. =.=. =.=. =.=. =.=. =.  */

/**
 * Example: Second
 *
 * Build JSON data from PHP array and retun as JSON response
 */

// Or build JSON data from array (PHP)
$json_var = [
  'hashtag' => 'HealthMatters',
  'id' => '072b3d65-9168-49fd-a1c1-a4700fc017e0',
  'sentiment' => [
    'negative' => 44,
    'positive' => 56,
  ],
  'total' => '3400',
  'users' => [
    [
      'profile_image_url' => 'http://a2.twimg.com/profile_images/1285770264/PGP_normal.jpg',
      'screen_name' => 'rayalrumbel',
      'text' => 'Tweet (A), #HealthMatters because life is cool :) We love this life and want to spend more.',
      'timestamp' => '{{$timestamp}}',
    ],
    [
      'profile_image_url' => 'http://a2.twimg.com/profile_images/1285770264/PGP_normal.jpg',
      'screen_name' => 'mikedingdong',
      'text' => 'Tweet (B), #HealthMatters because life is cool :) We love this life and want to spend more.',
      'timestamp' => '{{$timestamp}}',
    ],
    [
      'profile_image_url' => 'http://a2.twimg.com/profile_images/1285770264/PGP_normal.jpg',
      'screen_name' => 'ScottMili',
      'text' => 'Tweet (C), #HealthMatters because life is cool :) We love this life and want to spend more.',
      'timestamp' => '{{$timestamp}}',
    ],
    [
      'profile_image_url' => 'http://a2.twimg.com/profile_images/1285770264/PGP_normal.jpg',
      'screen_name' => 'yogibawa',
      'text' => 'Tweet (D), #HealthMatters because life is cool :) We love this life and want to spend more.',
      'timestamp' => '{{$timestamp}}',
    ],
  ],
];

// Output, response
echo json_encode($json_var);
```

> #### JSON File (JSON DATA):

```
{
    "hashtag": "HealthMatters", 
    "id": "072b3d65-9168-49fd-a1c1-a4700fc017e0", 
    "sentiment": {
        "negative": 44, 
        "positive": 56
    }, 
    "total": "3400", 
    "users": [
        {
            "profile_image_url": "http://a2.twimg.com/profile_images/1285770264/PGP_normal.jpg", 
            "screen_name": "rayalrumbel", 
            "text": "Tweet (A), #HealthMatters because life is cool :) We love this life and want to spend more.", 
            "timestamp": "{{$timestamp}}"
        }, 
        {
            "profile_image_url": "http://a2.twimg.com/profile_images/1285770264/PGP_normal.jpg", 
            "screen_name": "mikedingdong", 
            "text": "Tweet (B), #HealthMatters because life is cool :) We love this life and want to spend more.", 
            "timestamp": "{{$timestamp}}"
        }, 
        {
            "profile_image_url": "http://a2.twimg.com/profile_images/1285770264/PGP_normal.jpg", 
            "screen_name": "ScottMili", 
            "text": "Tweet (C), #HealthMatters because life is cool :) We love this life and want to spend more.", 
            "timestamp": "{{$timestamp}}"
        }, 
        {
            "profile_image_url": "http://a2.twimg.com/profile_images/1285770264/PGP_normal.jpg", 
            "screen_name": "yogibawa", 
            "text": "Tweet (D), #HealthMatters because life is cool :) We love this life and want to spend more.", 
            "timestamp": "{{$timestamp}}"
        }
    ]
}
```

> #### JSON Screeshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to format your domain objects to JSON is to use the [Marshal Serializer](https://github.com/Kingson-de/marshal-serializer).
Then pass the data to `json_encode` and send the correct Content-Type header for your needs.
If you are using a framework like Symfony, you don't need to take care of setting the headers manually. There you can use the [JsonResponse](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/JsonResponse.php).

For example the correct Content-Type for dealing with Javascript would be `application/javascript`.

Or if you need to support some pretty old browsers the safest would be `text/javascript`.

For all other purposes like a mobile app use `application/json` as the Content-Type.

Here is a small example:

```
<?php
...
$userCollection = [$user1, $user2, $user3];

$data = Marshal::serializeCollectionCallable(function (User $user) {
    return [
        'username' => $user->getUsername(),
        'email'    => $user->getEmail(),
        'birthday' => $user->getBirthday()->format('Y-m-d'),
        'followers => count($user->getFollowers()),
    ];
}, $userCollection);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you're doing this in WordPress, then there is a simple solution:

```
add_action( 'parse_request', function ($wp) {
    $data = /* Your data to serialise. */
    wp_send_json_success($data); /* Returns the data with a success flag. */
    exit(); /* Prevents more response from the server. */
})
```

Note that this is not in the `wp_head` hook, which will always return most of the head  even if you exit immediately. The `parse_request` comes a lot earlier in the sequence.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this [little PHP library](https://github.com/AlexisTM/Simple-Json-PHP). It sends the headers and give you an object to use it easily.

It looks like :

```
<?php
// Include the json class
include('includes/json.php');

// Then create the PHP-Json Object to suits your needs

// Set a variable ; var name = {}
$Json = new json('var', 'name'); 
// Fire a callback ; callback({});
$Json = new json('callback', 'name'); 
// Just send a raw JSON ; {}
$Json = new json();

// Build data
$object = new stdClass();
$object->test = 'OK';
$arraytest = array('1','2','3');
$jsonOnly = '{"Hello" : "darling"}';

// Add some content
$Json->add('width', '565px');
$Json->add('You are logged IN');
$Json->add('An_Object', $object);
$Json->add("An_Array",$arraytest);
$Json->add("A_Json",$jsonOnly);

// Finally, send the JSON.

$Json->send();
?>
```