# Problem while sending data through jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am sending data through jquery. my equivalent code is...

```
$('#pcpmnum').blur(function(){
//alert("HIiiiiii");
var pcpmnum = $("#pcpmnum").val();
if(pcpmnum === "" | pcpmnum === null)
    { 
        alert("Please Enter Mobile Number");
    }
else
    {
        alert(pcpmnum);
        $.post("searchpcp.php", {cntctnumber: "+pcpmnum+"}, function(){
            alert("Success");
                    }
    }

});
```

on my php file I have simply used.

```
echo "HIIII";
```

Is this $.post function is equivalent to Ajax function?

Comment: $.post is a shortcut for $.ajax so you don't have to fill in as many options.

Comment: `$.post` is a shorthand for `$.ajax` with certain presets (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post). From the code it should be calling the `searchpcp.php` properly, but why do you pass the `pcpmnum` as a string instead of passing its value (without the quotes and the +es)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply do

```
  {cntctnumber: pcpmnum, second:"second variable" }
```

and in the php file you can get the value as

```
$contact = $_POST["cntctnumber"]; // you will get the value of pcpmnum here
$sec = $_POST["second"]; // you will get "second variable" here
```

in the success call back the argument `data` in your case contains the server response e.g. in you php file you are echo`ing`

```
...
echo"howdy";
```

on the client side `data` will be holding this response

```
 $.post("searchpcp.php", {cntctnumber: pcpmnum, second:"second variable" }, function(data){
            alert(data);//howdy
           });
```

here are some useful links

[jQuery, Ajax, Json and Php](http://www.factsandpeople.com/facts-mainmenu-5/26-html-and-javascript/89-jquery-ajax-json-and-php)

[Returning JSON from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682260/returning-json-from-php-to-javascript)

Comment: If I need to send 2 variables? Second is this is equivalent to send Ajax request? what does it mean If I use `function(data)`

Comment: ill edit the answer for two vars and yes `$.post` uses ajax call at the backend it is just the short hand for `$.ajax`

Comment: I want to return an array of data. and fill the respective text field from that returned data. Suppose I have input with `id=firstname` and my second would be 'id=middlename'. I am firing querey in my PHP file. How would I return those data.

Comment: i have posted some links hope they'll help