# Android: PHP script to MS Access Database

Tags: java, php, android

Is there a PHP script that could fetch data from MSAccess Database? because my database is MsAccess. Then android could view that data in that webservice.. As i know.. PHP script is mostly used in MySQL database. Fetch the data and output will be in JSON Format. The android could get the data by using http post.

Comment: If you are running PHP on Windows, you can set up your Access DB in ODBC Manager, and use the ODBC SQL functions in PHP.

Comment: @AndrewR Ok sir. Is is possible that the output of that php script is in JSON Format?

Comment: If you can print something, you'll be able to use every format you want.

Comment: Could you send me some sample codes?

Answer (score 0):

This is some example and useful stuff on how to print JSON format using PHP:

- [Returning JSON from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682260/returning-json-from-php-to-javascript)
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.json.php