# How to use JSON when replying to an AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I built a message inbox, when you click on the message title an AJAX call is being made.
I want to know how can i reply to the call using JSON (server-side).

Also how can i use the JSON returned to me to extract the data.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax_handler.php',
    data: ({
        ajaxHook: 'getMessageReplies',
        messageID: $(this).attr('class')
    }),
    success: function ( messageLayout ){
    }
});
```

thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What platform are you using server side? PHP, Rails, MVC?

Comment: php and the server is linux :)

Comment: Did you see this SO post on returning JSON from PHP? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682260/returning-json-from-php-to-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `ajax_handler.php` you  can do something like

```
<? php

var $ajaxHook = $_POST["ajaxHook"];
var $messageID= $_POST["messageID"];

//perform some processing

$arr = array("title" => "john", "yourHtml" => "<p>hello</p>");
echo json_encode($arr);

?>
```

set the `dataType:'json'` so that the json is parsed

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax_handler.php',
    dataType:'json',
    data: ({
        ajaxHook: 'getMessageReplies',
        messageID: $(this).attr('class')
    }),
    success: function ( data ){    

      alert(data['title']);
      alert(data['yourHtml']);
    //process the result sent by the server
    }
});
```

Comment: and how i process it with jQ?

Comment: that depends what kind of data you are getting from the server

Comment: i'm returning two strings:
1. title
2. text + HTML