# $.each is looping over each character in my json and displaying undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

i need to loop over the below json but the below code is looping over each character in my json and displaying "undefined": (is there anything wrong with the below json??? Any help is appreciated)

```
{"news_id":"1","news_title":"News Title One","news_date":"2012-03-20","news_pic":"album-bb[6].jpg","news_desc":"Here goes the news title one Here goes the news title one Here goes the news title one Here goes the news title one.","gallid":"3"}
{"news_id":"2","news_title":"News Title Two","news_date":"2012-04-14","news_pic":"174863_163190093755777_2032987021_q.jpg","news_desc":"News Title Two News Title Two News Title Two News Title Two News Title Two News Title Two News Title Two News Title Two News Title Two News Title Two News Title Two News Title Two News Title Two News Title Two News Title Two News Title Two News Title Two News Title Two News Title Two News Title Two.","gallid":"0"}
```

This is my code which is being fired on click event:

```
var phpNews;
var NewsObject;

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#btnNewsPage").click(function()
    {
        $.post("server/news.php",null,function(e){
            NewsObject = e;
            $.mobile.changePage("#NewsPage");
        });
    });

    $('#NewsPage').live('pagebeforeshow',function(event, ui){
        var list;
        $.each(NewsObject, function(k,v){
            list = v.news_title;
        });

        $("#displayNews").html(list);
    });

})
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like, your `NewsObject` isn't a `JSON` object but string. It could happen because JQuery can't guess the response type, so you, probably, need to specify `dataType` for your `$.post` request ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)):

```
$.post("server/news.php", null, function(e){ ... }, 'json');
```

P.S. Also your `JSON` not looks valid, i expect to see something like `{'a':'b'}`, but you have `{'a':'b'} {'c':'d'}`.

**Updated.** Based on the comments below, i would suggest you to use next PHP code for your `server/news.php`:

```
<?php 

require "../includes/config.php"; 
require "../includes/h.conn.php"; 
require "../includes/admin.id.php"; 

$strSQL = "select * from news where admin_id=" .$admin_id; 
$objRS = mysql_query($strSQL);
$News_Obj = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($objRS)) {
    $record = array (
               "news_id" => $row['news_id'], 
               "news_title" => $row['news_title'], 
               "news_date" => $row['news_date']
    );
    $News_Obj[] = $record; 
}

// don't forget to clear after yourself: mysql_free_result, disconnect

header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($News_Obj);
?>
```

Also you can use Firebug to see what exactly returns the script and which HTTP or Javascript errors happen when you do a request.

Comment: Thank you gakhov for your reply. I have changed my code to the below as per your request but i am not being redirected to the news division now:

$.post("server/news.php",null,function(e){

NewsObject = e;

$.mobile.changePage("#NewsPage");

},

"json");

Comment: Do you generate `JSON` with PHP in a right way? [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682260/returning-json-from-php-to-javascript)

Comment: this is my news.php file:
<?php

require "../includes/config.php";

require "../includes/h.conn.php";

require "../includes/admin.id.php";


$strSQL="select * from news where admin_id=" .$admin_id;

$objRS=mysql_query($strSQL);

while ($row=mysql_fetch_object($objRS))

{
 $news_id = $row->news_id;
 
 $news_title = $row->news_title;
 
 $news_date = $row->news_date;
 
 $News_Obj["news_id"] = $news_id;
 
 $News_Obj["news_title"] = $news_title;
 
 $News_Obj["news_date"] = $news_date;
 
 echo json_encode($News_Obj);

}

?>

Comment: You need to put `header("Content-type: application/json");` before `echo` your data.

Comment: I have added the header("Content-type: application/json"); but m still facing the same issue of non redirection. I saw now ur comment about my json. how can i make my json looks like [{'a':'b'}, {'c':'d'}] ? do i have to alter my news.php to return something like that??

Comment: so, you can approve answer :)

Comment: extremely YES :) Thanks loadsss

Comment: hey gakhov. I am facing now another issue. it's about displaying my news data in a ul and li list. the code is:
$('#NewsPage').live('pagebeforeshow',function(event, ui){
Newslist = "";
$.each(NewsObject, function(k,v){
Newslist += "<li><a href='#'>" + v.news_title + "</a></li>";
});
$("ul#displayNews").html(Newslist);
});
in my html file i have:
<div data-role="content">
<div id="displayNews">
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
</ul>
</div>
</div>
note that Newslist is a global variable i defined in a file called gv_file.js and included in the head of html file.