# how to get length of 2d array in javascript and show data in dynamic div created from js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

what i need

- i need to show the count on icon .
- i need to make  dynamic div from input using array using javascript.

array structure

```
            Array
        (
            [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 50615
                [des] => PHARMA Pro&Pack Expo 2015 is organized by IPMMA and will be held at Mumbai, the economic capital of India. This show helps the exhibitors from all ove
                [membership] => 0
                [name] => Pharma Pro&Pack Expo
                [abbr_name] => Pharma Pro&Pack Expo
                [paid] => 0
                [event_wrapper] => 33587
                [event_samll_wrapper] => http://im.gifbt.com/industry/27-350x210.jpg
                [event_url] => pharma-propack-expo
                [website] => http://www.pharmapropack.com
                [eventType] => 1
                [venue_name] => Bombay Convention & Exhibition Centre (BCEC)
                [startDate] => 2015-05-13
                [endDate] => 2015-05-15
                [city] => Mumbai
                [country] => India
                [country_url] => india
                [country_shortname] => India
                [industry_id] => 27
                [industry_name] => Medical & Pharmaceutical
                [industry_url] => medical-pharma
                [event_status] => 
                [total_visitors] => 144
                [total_exhibitor] => 0
                [total_speakers] => 0
            )

            [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 57271
                [des] => The Iphex is a well acknowledged event in the pharmaceutical and healthcare industry and with the presence of pharmaceutical products and equipments,
                [membership] => 0
                [name] => Iphex
                [abbr_name] => Iphex
                [paid] => 0
                [event_wrapper] => 41539
                [event_samll_wrapper] => http://im.gifbt.com/industry/27-350x210.jpg
                [event_url] => iphex
                [website] => http://iphex-india.com/
                [eventType] => 1
                [venue_name] => Bombay Exhibition Centre
                [startDate] => 2015-05-13
                [endDate] => 2015-05-15
                [city] => Mumbai
                [country] => India
                [country_url] => india
                [country_shortname] => India
                [industry_id] => 27
                [industry_name] => Medical & Pharmaceutical
                [industry_url] => medical-pharma
                [event_status] => 
                [total_visitors] => 134
                [total_exhibitor] => 120
                [total_speakers] => 0
            )

            [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 175534
                [des] => The TENSYMP, organized by the CimlGlobal will take place from 13th May to the 15th May 2015 at the Courtyard by Marriott, India in Ahmedabad, India. T
                [membership] => 
                [name] => TENSYMP Ahmedabad
                [abbr_name] => TENSYMP Ahmedabad
                [paid] => 
                [event_wrapper] => 
                [event_samll_wrapper] => http://im.gifbt.com/industry/40-350x210.jpg
                [event_url] => tensymp-ahmedabad
                [website] => http://www.tensymp2015.org/
                [eventType] => 2
                [venue_name] => Gujarat International Finance Tec-City
                [startDate] => 2015-05-13
                [endDate] => 2015-05-15
                [city] => Ahmedabad
                [country] => India
                [country_url] => india
                [country_shortname] => India
                [industry_id] => 40
                [industry_name] => Scientific Instruments
                [industry_url] => scientific-instruments
                [event_status] => 
                [total_visitors] => 3
                [total_exhibitor] => 0
                [total_speakers] => 3
            )
```

js code

```
      var desktop="/app.php/notificationdetail";
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest
        url = desktop,
        params = url;
        http.open("POST", url, !0), http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8"), http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length), http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close"), 
        http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (4 == http.readyState && 200 == http.status) {


        var obj=http.responseText;
        alert(typeof obj);//string
        var parsed = JSON.parse(obj);



        for (var c in obj) {
        var newElement = document.createElement('div');
        newElement.id = obj[c]; newElement.className = "notification";
        newElement.innerHTML = obj[c];
        document.body.appendChild(newElement);
        } 
        }
        }, http.send(params);
```

problem

- i need to find length of array like if use php counts then it shows 2 array whereas  if i use .length() in js it doesn"t return required result.

o/p should should be

- count in notification should be 2 using javascript .
- i need to show ['id'],['name'],['city'] in dynamic div.

i have tried using for loop

```
for (var x=0; x<obj.length; x++)
 {
   var name= obj[x].name;
    console.log(name);//outputs : undefined
 }
```

Comment: Why you are not using for loop instead of for in loop ?

Comment: javacript doesn't have associative arrays...you will receive array of objects. Very helpful detailed post/tutorial: [access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: @charlietfl Objects. http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html

Comment: can anyone help how to get length of arrays in js i have tried :  var obj=http.responseText;
     console.log(obj.length); //it returning  23543 which is wrong . if handled through php (counts )its works fine ..

Comment: we cannot find length of 2d arrays in js

Comment: i have tried : for(var i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++){console.log(testArray[i]);}

Comment: `obj` is just a json **string**, your loop is not going to do what you are expecting.  Looping through `parsed` is the correct thing but without knowing the structure, it's hard to guess what's the internal will look like.

Comment: Or are you saying that calling `/app.php/notificationdetail` will actually return that `Array (...)` that you pasted above?  If so, that's not a valid JSON format.  Try paste that **url** (**http://..../app.php/notificationdetail**) in the browser, copy it and edit your question and paste the actual json content returned from php.

Comment: same array i m sending getting same array format in response.text

Comment: its not json its array format i need to fetch data from array is quite simple

Comment: i have tried to fetch  for (var x=0; x<obj.length; x++)
     {
       console.log(obj[x]);
     }

Answer (score 0):

**On Getting the number of rows (object count) and columns (field count):**

Not familiar w/ php `Array`, but it looks to me it's a one dimensional array with **HashTable** structure for each array element.

Just to confirm add `console.log(parsed);` after your `var parsed = JSON.parse(obj);` line.  You should see something like `[{id:50615,des:'PHARMA...',...},{id:57271,des:'The Iphex...',...},{...}]`.

If so, `parsed.length` should give you the number of objects (rows) in your data structure and `Object.keys(parsed[0]).length` will give you the number of columns / fields in the object.

***NOTE***: Only thing here is I am assuming that all objects in the array have equal numbers of fields. If not you might have to loop through the array and figure out the max length of each object in the array and use it as column count.

**On displaying specific fields:**

Once you understand how your array of objects are layout, you can just use `Array.map` function to pull out certain fields from inside your original array like so:

`var model = parsed.map(function(o) { return { id: o.id, name: o.name, city: o.city }; });`

and use the now model which now should only contains an array of object having **id, name** and **city** fields however you like.

You seems to already know how to do DOM manipulation so I won't go there.  The only suggestion I can give is to either use string concatenation and bulk inject it to a DOM element `innerHTML` or use `documentFragment` approach for performance.  See: http://jsperf.com/concat-vs-docfrag/4

Comment: i have tried like console.log(obj.length);
     $(".notification1").append(obj.length);

Comment: i have tried for(var i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++){console.log(testArray[i]);}

Comment: That's why I said we need to see how that php Array is getting serialized into Json. And you can see the result by either doing `console.log(obj)` after `var obj = http.responseText` above and see how the JSON string looks like or I am guessing it will be what I am expecting in my answer. If not, once the JSON is known, it's just a matter of figuring that out.  Without that, it's very hard to understand.  JavaScript does not have 2 dimensional array, rather to do 2d array it will embed array within the container array like `[[..],[..],[..]]`.

Comment: same array i m sending getting same array format in response.text

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 50615
          )

Comment: That's not a valid JSON then. You will need to parse that thing into a valid javascript object notation using some sort of a custom parser or have php return a valid JSON from server side.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682260/returning-json-from-php-to-javascript