# cross-domain form post with ajax jsonp returns error: {"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"success"}

Tags: ajax, forms, cross-domain, jsonp, bigcommerce

I'm trying to post form data to a php file that will then handle a mysql request. But before I do the mysql, I'm trying to connect to the php file.

The request is Cross-Domain.

When i submit the form, i get the error: {"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"success"}

You can see the test page here: http://jonathan-tapia.mybigcommerce.com/store-locator/

form code:

```
<div class="map-search">
    <h1>Give us your zip code. We'll tell you where to find us.</h1>
    <div id="map-form">
        <form id="lookup-form" action="http://dev.visioncourse.com/customers/baldguy/index.php" method="post">
            <p>Within
                <select id="distance" name="distance">
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option selected="selected" value="25">25</option>
                    <option value="50">50</option>
                    <option value="100">100</option>
                </select>
                miles of 
                <input id="zipcode" type="text" name="postalcode" value="" size="8" /> 
                <input id="lookup" type="submit" value="Look Up" />
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="map-results">&nbsp;</div>
```

updated JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
//submit form
$('#lookup-form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var formdata = $(this);
    var link = formdata.attr('action');
    var distance = $('#distance').val();
    var zipcode = $('#zipcode').val();
    console.log('.\n..\n...\n....\nSubmitting Form\n....\n...\n..\n.');
    $.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        type: 'POST',
        url: link,
        data: {
            'distance': distance,
            'postalcode': zipcode
        },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        error: function(data) {
            console.log('error: ' + data);
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('success: ' + data);
        },
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        }
    });
});
```

// ]]>

updated php file:

```
<?php
$arr = array();
$distance = $_POST['distance']
$zip = $_POST['postalcode'];
if(isset($distance) && isset($zip)) {
    array_push($arrr, {'d': $distance, 'z': $zip});
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

?>

error i'm receiving from console:

```
GET http://dev.visioncourse.com/customers/baldguy/index.php?callback=jQuery17203092896034941077_1451698154204&distance=25&postalcode=85251       jquery.min.js:4
```

EDIT:
The php file will get the distance and zip code from the form and connect to a mysql database for a google maps store locator. so when a person submits the radius and the zip code it will display results. but all of this will be on the php file.

The file doing the form submission will submit the form, wait for the php to do it's work, then display the php file with the results

Comment: crossdomain no accept `POST` data, only `GET`

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `data: {"distance": distance, "zipcode": zipcode},`. 
In your code you insert the value of the variables twice instead of a name and a value.

Also, you need to send the zipcode with the name of 'postalcode'. Otherwise your phpscript wouldn't find it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I made that change and encountered another one.


Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <          http://dev.visioncourse.com/customers/baldguy/index.php?callback=jQuery1720553592529380694_1451692338259&distance=25&zipcode=85251



error: {"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"success"}

Comment: updated ajax:

$.ajax({
   crossDomain: true,
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'http://dev.visioncourse.com/customers/baldguy/index.php',
   data: {'distance': distance, 'postalcode': zipcode},
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   error: function(data) {
    console.log('error: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
   },
   success: function(data) {
    console.log('success: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
   },
   xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
   }
  });

Comment: the unexpected < is from my php. When i look at the source, it says <p></p><p></p>

Comment: For the php. Set the content-type to json and encode your output... http://stackoverflow.com/q/682260/2179591

Comment: do i want that if i'm going to add html to the php file? i'm going to add text to the php file, i'm just trying to connect to the file right now, but after I connect i'm going to add content to the php file. it will eventually connect to a mysql database for a google maps store locator. so when a person submits the radius and the zip code it will display results. but all of this will be on the php file. The file doing the form submission will submit the form, wait for the php to do it's work, then display the php file with the results

Comment: The error in your startpost isn't an error. It only tells you that the request is made to the server. And for a proper "program", you want to return an array with results from the php file and iterate over it by Javascript to add it to the html.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way:

javascript:

```
<script>
var formdata = $(this);
var link = formdata.attr('action');
var distance = $('#distance').val();
var zipcode = $('#zipcode').val();
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: link,
   data: {"distance": distance,"postalcode": zipcode},
   async: false,
   jsonpCallback: 'jsonp_callback',//name of function returned from php
   contentType: "application/json",
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   success: function(r) {
       console.log(r);
   },
   error: function(e) {
        alert(e.message);
   }
});
</script>
```

php:

```
<?php
$arr = array();
$distance = $_GET['distance'];//sample 123
$zip = $_GET['postalcode'];//sample 65455
if(isset($distance) && isset($zip)) {
    $arr = array('d'=> $distance, 'z'=> $zip);
}
$json = 'jsonp_callback(';
$json .= json_encode($arr);
$json .= ');';
echo $json;
?>
```

response:

```
jsonp_callback({"d":123,"z":65455});
```