# How can i receive more than one responses in ajax in the same function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

here is my simple code

```
  $.ajax({
            url:'action.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data:{getcart:1},
            success:function(response){
                $('#getcart').html(response);//want to display $return_value (from action page)
                $('#getcart2').html(response);//want to display $return_value2 (from action page)
            }
        });
```

Here i am sending request to action.php

and if in action.php i have echo two variables separately for example.

```
$return_value = " //Some html here ";  echo $return_value;
$return_value2= "//some other html";  echo $return_value2;
```

So the question is  in ajax i have function with argument response . how i will be able to receive these both variables from php and display it in different divs.
i hope you guys help me. thanks.

Comment: take a look to [Returning JSON from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682260/returning-json-from-php-to-javascript)

Comment: return an array or object from your PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Send the responses as JSON.

In PHP

```
$return = array( $return_value, $return_value2 );
echo json_encode($return);
```

In Javascript

```
var response = JSON.parse(response);
$("#getcart").html(response[0]);
$("#getcart2").html(response[1]);
```

Comment: @spaceman sir, in my code there is while loop and i need to echo $return_value inside the loop and $return_value2 outside the loop.....but here where should i echo json_encode($return) . if i echo it inside the loop not getting any data but if i echo it outside the loop ; not getting repeated data through while loop but getting $return_value2.

Comment: Don't echo $return_value inside the loop, but save it into a variable instead. `while(...) { ... $return_value = 1; ... } $return_value2 = 2;` The only echo that needs to happen is `echo json_encode($return);` and it definitely should be outside the loop.

Comment: and where to create an array?

Answer (score 1):

your could return a json from action

```
echo json_encode(array('cart' => $return_value, 'cart2' => $return_value2));
```

then in your js,

```
       $.ajax({
            url:'action.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data:{getcart:1},
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(response){
                $('#getcart').html(response.cart1);//want to display $return_value (from action page)
                $('#getcart2').html(response.cart2);//want to display $return_value2 (from action page)
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `json_encode` in order to get multiple records or data.

<kbd>action.php</kbd>

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$array = array(
               'var1'=> 'var value 1',
               'var2'=> 'var value 2'
// more variables to go
);
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

and then read your variables in <kbd>JS</kbd>

```
dataType: 'json',
success:function(response){
    console.log(response.var1);
    console.log(response.var2);
    $('#getcart').html(response.var1);
    $('#getcart2').html(response.var2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php) to create an object like:

```
$array = [
    "return_value" => " //Some html here ",
    "return_value2" => "//some other html",
];
echo json_encode($array)
```

Then add `dataType: 'json'` to your ajax options. The `response` then will be an object like:

```
{
    "return_value" => " //Some html here ",
    "return_value2" => "//some other html",
}
```

Where you can access the specific values with e.g. `response.return_value2` and thus separate them.