# Ajax success not running

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

So im having a weird issue. I made a small application on my machine that works fine but when I upload to a school server it stops working. What I am doing is accessing json data with ajax. I have tested and I am getting the correct json responses, I am connecting to the database just fine and the ajax is running every two seconds as it should. But the code in the success section of the ajax never runs. The database on the server is identical to the one on my machine, the connection has been troubleshooted and works great but still the ajax success code doesn't run. Thanks in advance!

```
setInterval(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'JSONFile.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (retrieved) {
                    $.each(retrieved, function (index, i) {
                         alert('This line of code is the problem. This alert does not run but should');
                    });
                }
            });
        }, 2000);
```

Comment: put up an error call back and see if that get's fired instead :-)

Comment: Is the JSONFile.php file hosted on same web server (same host, port etc) ?

Comment: Open the console and check for errors there.

Comment: added an error call and it broke more, JSONFile.php is on the server and is giving a response and I have no errors in the console

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I am using version 3.3.1

Comment: Putting an alert in a callback in a set interval is a terrible idea, use console.log instead

Comment: Have you tried looking through devtools network panel? does it show the request and response?

Comment: **success** has been removed from jQuery 3.3.1 - no matter what you do, it won't get called.  You need to read the documentation carefully.

Comment: Switched versions of jquery to have it supported. Also looking at the devtools and not getting any errors. It is showing good responses

Comment: If this is a new project, I suggest you take a little time to learn to work with jQuery 3+.  It is a good idea to use the most current versions of tools.

Answer (score 0):

If not yet done, please ensure that the PHP file returns a JSON response from the server. AJAX is set to communicate with the server using JSON format, and if the server does not responsd that way, AJAX will not conside the response as success.

Check out the [Returning JSON from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31165265/2289769).

**Update:**

Try to run the following code while having the Developer Tools of the browser open. Once the app stops at the breakpoint, check the `data` in the browser and see what you've got. It is most likely a string in JSON format, that means you will need to parse it to be able to iterate through it's items.

```
success: function(data){
    debugger; // inspect the returned data
    var obj = JSON.parse(data); // returned data is a string and so, to work on it, it needs to be parsed
    $.each(obj, function (index, i) {
        $('<div class="Post"><h2>' + i.UserName + '</h2><p>' + i.Content + '</p></div>').prependTo($('#MainContent')).fadeOut(1).fadeIn(1000); }
    );
}
```

Comment: In the following code I have now gotten the first alert to run but not the second

Comment: success: function(data){
               alert("hi");
               $.each(data, function (index, i) {
                    //prepend with a fade in animation
                    alert('Hi');
                    $('<div class="Post"><h2>' + i.UserName + '</h2><p>' + i.Content + '</p></div>').prependTo($('#MainContent')).fadeOut(1).fadeIn(1000);
                });
           }

Comment: Correction: commenting out datatype: 'json', allows the inside to run but then .each wont work

Comment: try to place a debugger right before the $.each() method and check the data yourself in the browser. You will then understand what type of data is received, and based on that make your next move.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some suggestions that you can try.

Answer (score -1):

jQuery 3 is coded using **done**, **fail** and **always**

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqXHR object for this request
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });
```

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and
>   jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use
>   jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.