# Why is my JSON is incorrectly returned as HTML from PHP?

Tags: php, json

I have the following PHP code to retrieve data from the database and return it as JSON:

```
    <?php


include('connect.php');

$sql="select * from parent";
mysqli_query($conn,$sql)or die("Error");
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

    //create an array
    $emparray = array();
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $emparray[] = $row;
    }
    
    $json_data = json_encode($emparray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

// Output the JSON data with line breaks
    echo nl2br($json_data);


?>
```

I expect it to return

```
[{"parent_id":"1","name":"John Smith","mobile":"123456789","cpr":"123456789","email":"john.smith@example.com","address":"123 Main St","longitude":"0.00000000","latitude":"0.00000000"},{"parent_id":"2","name":"Jane Doe","mobile":"234567890","cpr":"234567890","email":"jane.doe@example.com","address":"456 Oak St","longitude":"0.00000000","latitude":"0.00000000"},{"parent_id":"3","name":"Bob Johnson","mobile":"345678901","cpr":"345678901","email":"bob.johnson@example.com","address":"789 Maple St","longitude":"0.00000000","latitude":"0.00000000"}]
```

But it actually returns

```
<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js"
></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("cb118c40b2bb71e1d651fbe4983c0a6b");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/";
```

I know this because, in my C# client, I do:

```
var client = new HttpClient();

// Send an HTTP GET request to the web API
var response = await client.GetAsync("URL");

// Read the content of the response and deserialize it into a .NET object
var contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var content = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Parent []>(contentString);

// Loop through the data and output it
foreach (var item in content)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Parent ID: {0}", item.parent_id);
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", item.name);
    Console.WriteLine("Mobile: {0}", item.mobile);
    Console.WriteLine("CPR: {0}", item.cpr);
    Console.WriteLine("Email: {0}", item.email);
}
```

And `contentString` is actually the HTML shown, rather than JSON, causing `JsonSerializer.Deserialize()` to throw an exception.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `Message='<' is an invalid start of a value.` indicates that the content you are trying to deserialize is actually XML, not JSON.   To debug this and confirm, first get the content as a string by doing `var contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` and then do `var content =System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Parent[]>(contentString);`  Then you will be able to log or view in a debugger the content string and find out what it actually is.

Comment: If XML is being returned, it might be because you you are getting an error response.  To check whether an error was returned before deserializing, use [`HttpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.issuccessstatuscode?view=net-7.0)

Comment: i have tried this and the same error apear

Comment: OK, I think I may see your problem.  I'm not a PHP developer but according to its manual page [`nl2br`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) inserts line breaks by inserting **`<br />`**.  That will result in malformed JSON.  Try eliminating the call to `nl2br`.

Comment: also i tried it without nl2br and the same error apear

Comment: Then please [edit] your question to show the JSON being returned, we can't help you with JSON deserialization issues unless we can see your JSON.

Comment: But in your PHP code you may also need to do `header('Content-type: application/json');`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31165265) by aesede to [Returning JSON from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/682260).

Comment: header('Content-type: application/json'); itried this solution also show error

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with the `contentString` shown in your question.  It is deserialized successfully and can be printed to the console, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/RkzZc4.  The JSON returned cannot be what is shown in your question, it must include a `<` somewhere.  E.g. if you are examining the returned content in a browser and it is actually HTML, you need to view the source to see what is actually returned.  Good luck!

Comment: I rewrote your question to clarify that help is needed on the PHP side to correctly return JSON.  Please check my edits, and if they are incorrect, feel free to undo my edit and [roll back](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271935) to an earlier version such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76289242/9).  Good luck!